# How can I remove bounding whitespace of unknown origin that surrounds ajax response text?

Tags: php, html, jquery, removing-whitespace

I have an ajax script that inserts its response text into a div. This response text is surrounded by whitespace that appears to come from nowhere. I have spent hours looking around for a solution and nothing work. I have tried using `trim()` on the server side (PHP), and the following on the client side (javascript/jquery):

```
data = data.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g,'');
data = $.trim(data);
```

but none of these things work. Has anyone else experienced this before, and how can I solve this issue? By the way, the same thing happens in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera. Also, when I inspect the html in the browser there is no indication that the whitespace is there, but visually it is definitely there.

Comment: this probably has nothing to do with ajax and everything to do with CSS. Use your browsers' object inspector to see what elements are being inserted, and what their properties are.

Comment: are you sure it is whitespace and not HTML `&nbsp;` ?

Comment: This did not solve the problem: ``data = data.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');``.

Answer (score 0):

Could you also post the div that you are using as well? As well as the JQuery that you use to insert the text into the div?

Here are some things you can try -

1. Alert the data and see if you can see the whitespace there
2. Place the text into it as a serialized string (http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and see if you notice the whitespace there.

Answer (score 0):

It can be 'non-breaking' space (with char code 160).

Comment: Should I remove that with PHP or jQuery? How would I remove it?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you remove them. Just use appropriate `regexp` for this.